# NotSupportedException thrown when instantiating a DataContext on wp8

Tags: c#, linq, exception, windows-phone-8, datacontext

I'm currently using `VS2012 Express`, writing in `C#`, and targeting `WP8`.  My testing is being done with the emulator.

I've been following the example here: 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingtheDatabase

My problem is, every time I try to instantiate a `DataContext` object (well, my derived class) I get a `NotSupportedException` in `System.Data.Linq.ni.dll`.  The line throwing the exception is the constructor calling `base(ConnectionString)`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how I can get more information to help me sort this out?

Comment: What's the exact exception message?

Comment: just put your code then it will be easy to test your code ..

Comment: The error message was just the connection string.  I figured it out thought: apparently the file extension matters here.  I changed the extension to .sdf and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently db files can only use SDF extensions.  When I modified the name of my data file to use .SDF, everything worked fine.